# Windows 10 Universal App - Socket connection recurrent readings

Tags: c#, windows, sockets, windows-10-universal

I am following the Socket Example about StreamSockets. I can read from the server as a client. The example is https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/es-ES/79eda064-473d-4398-8fe3-72369e686c3c/comunicacion-tcpcip-con-streamsocket-y-datawriterdatareader?forum=esdevwindows

I'm building a Windows 10 Universal Application and I need continuous readings from a socket connection. I'm getting the first reading but then only empty strings.

Thanks!

[Image capture response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xusIB.jpg)

```
         Private StreamSocket socketForServer;
        Private DataWriter cfaStreamWriter;
        Private DataReader cfaStreamReader;

        // Read socket data
        Private Async void ReadData()
        {
                If (socketForServer == null) Then Return;
                uint s = await cfaStreamReader.LoadAsync(1024);
                String Data = cfaStreamReader.ReadString(s);
                PrintData(Data);
                var ignore = Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () >=
                ReadData());  
        }

        // Connect to the bid controller through TCP Socket.
        Public Async Task<bool> Connect()
        {
                socketForServer = New StreamSocket();
                var hostname = New HostName(deviceSPACS_IP);
                await socketForServer.ConnectAsync(hostname, deviceSPACS_PORT.ToString());
                // send login
                SendRawMessage("WELCOME TO SERVER");
                cfaStreamReader = New DataReader(socketForServer.InputStream)
                {
                    InputStreamOptions = InputStreamOptions.Partial
                };
               ReadData();
                Return True;
        }

        // Disconnect from bid Controller 
        Public bool Disconnect()
        {
            If (socketForServer == null) Then Return False;
            SendRawMessage("GOOD BYE AL SERVER");    
            cfaStreamReader.Dispose();
            cfaStreamReader = null;
            socketForServer.Dispose();
            socketForServer = null;
            Return True;
        }


        Private Async void SendRawMessage(String message)
        {
            cfaStreamWriter = New DataWriter(socketForServer.OutputStream);                   cfaStreamWriter.WriteString(message + "\r\n");
                await cfaStreamWriter.StoreAsync();
                await cfaStreamWriter.FlushAsync();
                cfaStreamWriter.DetachStream();

            cfaStreamWriter.Dispose();
            cfaStreamWriter = null;
        }
```

Comment: How do you send and read data? From your posted code, I don't know how you use these methods. Besides, there is a official [StreamSocket sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/StreamSocket) in GitHub. You can have a check.